# How to resize the image displayed from sql queying?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, blob

I am in testing phase of a new project ,just learning my self how to work with php , so i know pdo is better and will learn it soon

Now to the question

I wrote a registration page which includes profile picture and i am saving it in the fb fine , but i am having issue with retrieving it and resizing it

This is the code requesting the image

```
<?php
include("dbconfig.php");
// Create connection
$conn=mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password) or die('Error1');;

mysql_select_db("motorklq_glmindb",$conn) or die('Error2');


$result = mysql_query("SELECT fname,lname,profilepic FROM gtable");

echo "<table><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Image</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    print "<tr><td>".$row['fname']."</td><td>".$row['lname']."</td><td>".'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['profilepic'] ) . '" />'."</td></tr>";
}
print "</table>";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

now the image displayed is full size , how can i make it 20*20 resize without any change in aspect ratio ?

Comment: for displaying the image, you can give width and height to the image tag, either give width/height and it will adjust the other appropriately. Though the picture quality doesn't looks nice at times. But if it is a thumbnail it will look cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add profilepic in select query and change query

```
SELECT fname,lname,profilepic FROM gtable
```

and

```
base64_encode( $row['image'] )
```

to

```
base64_encode( $row['profilepic'] )
```

in your table image storing in profilepic field

**EDIT**

image size

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['profilepic'] ) . '"  width="42" height="42">
```

check this link for more
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_img_height

Comment: how can i resize the displayed image .. thanks for the help , by the time i edited the first questions , the answers was given

Comment: @user2959053, instead of editing the same question. Add new questions. Do some googling before posting a question here. The question would have asked before

Answer (score 0):

image field missing in your query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT fname,lname,profilepic FROM gtable");
```

Comment: image displayed is full size , how can i make it 20*20 resize without any change in aspect ratio ?